# Strange behavior when updating entity FK in LightSwitch app

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, promise, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I have three entities: `selected_spo`, `selected_product`, `selected_stock`.

I need to update a FK in the existing entity `selected_stock` in order to link it to the newly created entity `new_spoxs`.
`new_spoxs` has mandatory FKs with entities `selected_spo` and `selected_product`

If I call `myapp.applyChanges()` immediately after I do the assignments then the whole update process enters in a very strange state.
The newly created entity `new_spoxs` is saved to DB but the FK `selected_stock.supplier_po_x_stocks` is not created.

There is no error in the `[Function onError]` of the Promise `myapp.applyChanges().then...` The UI keeps telling me that there are *Unsaved Changes* but *Save changes* button has no effect.

I also tried to solve this in more steps.
First create the new entity, do a `myapp.applyChanges()`, update the FK link `selected_stock.supplier_po_x_stocks = new_spoxs;` and then do another final `myapp.applyChanges()`.
This was also NOT successful without that delay.

It ONLY works if I use a delay as you can see in the code !
This is totally not OK.

Where I am wrong ?

Or maybe this is a bug in LightSwitch ?!

```
var p_spo = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.storeData.supplier_poes_SingleOrDefault(id_spo_selected);
var p_product = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.storeData.products_SingleOrDefault(id_product_selected);
var p_stock = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.storeData.stocks_SingleOrDefault(id_stock_selected);
var promises_to_execute = [p_spo, p_product, p_stock];

var promises_executor = promises_to_execute.map(function (_p) {
    return _p.execute();
}); 

WinJS.Promise.join(promises_executor).then(function (promises_result) {

    var selected_spo = promises_result[0].results[0];
    var selected_product = promises_result[1].results[0];
    var selected_stock = promises_result[2].results[0];

//Next create a new supplier_po_x_stocks entity

    //var new_spoxs = new myapp.supplier_po_x_stock();
    var new_spoxs = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.storeData.supplier_po_x_stocks.addNew();
    new_spoxs.product = selected_product;
    new_spoxs.supplier_po = selected_spo;
    new_spoxs.qty_requested = qty_to_be_ordered;
    new_spoxs.qty_entered = 0;

//This is not working without WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000) ...  !!!  NOT OK !!!
    selected_stock.supplier_po_x_stocks = new_spoxs;

    WinJS.Promise.timeout(1000).then(function () {
        myapp.applyChanges().then(
            function () {
                screen.v_spo_products_to_be_ordereds.refresh();
                msls.showMessageBox('Save ok');
            },
            function (err) {
                msls.showMessageBox(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
            });
    });

}, function (err) {
    msls.showMessageBox(JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
});
```

Comment: Where is the `new_spoxs` or the `selected_stock` saved, do you have a promise for that?

Comment: You definitely need to  `return` the promise chains from all your functions (including callbacks).